# Permission denied error while trying to register and email to user on website using django 1.6 + django-allauth on CentOS 6.5 + httpd webserver

Tags: django, email, centos

I am running Django 1.6 framework on CentOS 6.5 (AWS EC2 instance) and serving the website using httpd web server. I am using django-allauth package for user account signup. When one signs up, allauth sends an outbound email to the user and then the user has to confirm their email address by clicking on a link in the email. Here are the corresponding SMTP settings in settings.py:

```
# smtp server settings for gmail
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<mypassword>'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

On my development server (which is also a CentOS 6.5 on a Virtualbox on my Windows laptop), on which I just run the Django based webserver (using python manage.py runserver), all is well i.e. When I do a registration, it is able to send an outbound email and I am able to successfully register and login subsequently.

But on the test server (AWS EC2 instance running CentOS 6.5 using httpd and using Django 1.6 on it), when I try to register, it ends up in the page throwing a "Permission denied" error, the details of the stack trace which I am pasting below.

```
    error at /accounts/signup/
    [Errno 13] Permission denied
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://<server_ip_address>/accounts/signup/
    Django Version: 1.6.2
    Exception Type: error
    Exception Value:    
    [Errno 13] Permission denied
    Exception Location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py in create_connection, line 567
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.6.6
    Python Path:    
    ['/var/www/html/firstProject',
     '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']    

    Request Method: POST
        Request URL: http://<server_ip_address>/accounts/signup/

        Django Version: 1.6.2
        Python Version: 2.6.6
        Installed Applications:
        ('django.contrib.admin',
         'django.contrib.auth',
         'django.contrib.contenttypes',
         'django.contrib.sessions',
         'django.contrib.messages',
         'django.contrib.staticfiles',
         'django.contrib.sites',
         'print_string',
         'CompanyApp',
         'UserApp',
         'south',
         'allauth',
         'allauth.account',
         'allauth.socialaccount',
         'sendgrid',
         'django_cleanup')
        Installed Middleware:
        ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
         'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
         'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
         'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


        Traceback:
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
          114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
          69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
          62.                                             **kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
          133.                                                           **kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
          87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in post
          78.             response = self.form_valid(form)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in form_valid
          164.                                self.get_success_url())
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in complete_signup
          149.                          signal_kwargs=signal_kwargs)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in perform_login
          117.             send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=signup)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in send_email_confirmation
          278.                                                     signup=signup)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py" in send_confirmation
          56.         confirmation.send(request, signup=signup)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py" in send
          131.                                 ctx)
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py" in send_mail
          93.         msg.send()
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
          274.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
          87.             new_conn_created = self.open()
        File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
          48.                                            local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py" in __init__
          239.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py" in connect
          295.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
          273.         return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py" in create_connection
          567.     raise error, msg

        Exception Type: error at /accounts/signup/
        Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am splitting my hair on why on my dev environment (Django on CentOS 6.5 running Django test web server + django-allauth) it works fine, whereas on the AWS EC2 instance running CentOS 6.5 + Django 1.6 + httpd + django-allauth, it ends up in this error. Has the root cause of this error do with the server's inability to send outbound emails? Or is it something else that is the root cause?

Any insights on how to resolve this issue and keep moving forward? I am open for change (including the OS if needed). But any resolution that would need the least changes would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912553/permission-denied-when-trying-to-send-verification-email

Comment: Thanks. No I didn't stumble upon that one during my search. I am taking a look into that to see if I can figure it out.